PPI vs DPI difference
I’ve been working on some print design projects and keep coming across the terms DPI and PPI. I know they both relate to image resolution, but I’m a bit confused about the exact difference between the two and how they impact print quality.
Can someone break down what DPI vs. PPI really means in the context of print design?
Also, why does it matter so much when preparing files for print?
I’d love to get some insights on when to use each and any tips for ensuring my designs look sharp and professional when printed.

Why does it matter so much when preparing files for print? It does not, not really. But its a quick and dirty tool to estimate what you need.

Only hardware has DPI. "Dots" are physical. They have a fixed size.
Images are expressed as PPI. Pixels are not physical until they are printed or displayed or somehow rendered -- by hardware.
